# HTTP Error when uploading images

Tags: uploads

I am getting an 'HTTP Error' when uploading images to posts. What could be the reason for this? It doesn't happen all the time, sometimes I get the error, try again, and the file uploads. Actually the file always seems to upload, however it doesn't generate the different sized images or anything.

Answer (score 0):

There a couple of different solutions depending on the cause of the problem.

In your case it seems that is not a upload problem. I would rather try adding [the following plugin](https://github.com/getsource/default-to-gd)

```
<?php
/*
Plugin Name: Default to GD
Plugin URI: http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/default-to-gd
Description: Sets GD as default WP_Image_Editor class.
Author: Mike Schroder
Version: 1.0
Author URI: http://www.getsource.net/
*/

function ms_image_editor_default_to_gd( $editors ) {
    $gd_editor = 'WP_Image_Editor_GD';

    $editors = array_diff( $editors, array( $gd_editor ) );
    array_unshift( $editors, $gd_editor );

    return $editors;
}
add_filter( 'wp_image_editors', 'ms_image_editor_default_to_gd' );
?>
```

This will change the default image editor